# Configuring StructureMap with WCF for IoC (Dependency injection)

Tags: c#, wcf, structuremap, configure

I read this article of Jimmy Bogard's, and I got the idea of how to create dependency injection on a service. I read these two articles : http://blogs.planbsoftware.co.nz/?p=492 and http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/ .

So my question after reading the articles is, where to write those classes that are described there (StructureMapInstanceProvider , StructureMapServiceBehavior , StructureMapServiceHost , StructureMapServiceHostFactory ). Should I write those on the service or on the host of the service ? Another question is where to configure the service ? In host's global.asax, or on the service's global.asax ?

Can someone explain me ?

Answer (score 3):

The articles discussing WCF and StructureMap together are fairly old. I have created a minimal application that uses WCF and StructureMap and it can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/ramondeklein/wcfstructuremap).

## Explanation

WCF creates instances via the `IInstanceProvider` interface, so we need to create a custom instance provider that creates the instances via StructureMap. This instance provider uses the container to resolve the requested types:

```
public class StructureMapInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    private readonly Type _type;

    public StructureMapInstanceProvider(IContainer container, Type type)
    {
        _container = container;
        _type = type;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(_type);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        _container.Release(instance);
    }
}
```

Each endpoint can have its own instance provider by setting the `InstanceProvider` of the `DispatchRuntime` class. This is typically done. This is typically done from inside a service behaviour (`IServiceBehavior`) in the `ApplyDispatchBehavior`).

```
public class StructureMapServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapServiceBehavior(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (var channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.OfType<ChannelDispatcher>())
        {
            foreach (var ed in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new StructureMapInstanceProvider(_container, serviceDescription.ServiceType);
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior needs to be added to the `ServiceHost` so it is applied to all services within that host:

```
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new StructureMapServiceBehavior(container));
```

The services will now be created via StructureMap and you can use dependency injection in your services. This solution doesn't use any static variables or factory patterns (as seen in some other examples that I have seen).

## Nested containers

You probably want nested containers when the `InstanceContextMode` of your service is set to `PerCall` or `PerSession`. You need to create these nested containers in the `IInstanceProvider.GetInstance` call and dispose the nested container in the `IInstanceProvider.ReleaseInstance`. To make sure you can correlate the `GetInstance` and `ReleaseInstance` additional information can be added to the instance context (via the `Extensions` property. You can find the required changes in this [commit](https://github.com/ramondeklein/wcfstructuremap/commit/6d7e0de8d7501469bbfe9944e32e111b3e516e63).

## Singleton services (caveat)

Singletons are already created in the constructor of the `ServiceHost`, so you cannot use a behavior to alter the creation. Singletons can only be created in WCF if they have a default constructor (and IoC services typically don't have these). If you want to use a service host with StructureMap and singletons, then you can pass the singleton directly to the container:

```
using (var container = Register())
{
    var singleton = container.Resolve<HelloWcfServer>();
    using (var host = new ServiceHost(singleton, Settings.BaseUri))
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```